# Musical instruments and their codes

Tags: knowledge, cipher, pattern

*Fill the empty cells under **ONE**, **TWO**, **THREE** and **FOUR***

---

**ONE**

| Musical Instrument | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Ektara | I5E6 |
| Masenqo |  |

---

**TWO**

| Musical Instrument | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Erhu |  |
| Gunjac | C7G6 |

---

**THREE**

| Musical Instrument | Code |
| --- | --- |
|  | R6B9 |
| Shamisen | J5S8 |

---

**FOUR**

| Musical Instrument | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Cavaquinho | P8C10 |
|  | A10C7 |

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The codes for each instrument always take the form *letter-number-letter-number*, and can be derived as follows:

> 1. The first letter of the instrument's **country of origin** (in English).
>  2. The **number of letters** in that country's shortform English name.
>  3. The **first letter of the instrument** itself.
>  4. The **number of letters** in the instrument's name.

This can be seen in the codes already known:

> [Ektara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ektara) I5E6 (origin: India)
>  [Gunjac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunjac) C7G6 (origin: Croatia)
>  [Shamisen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamisen) J5S8 (origin: Japan)
>  [Cavaquinho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavaquinho) P8C10 (origin: Portugal)

With this in mind, the gaps can now be filled as follows:

> 1. [Masenqo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masenqo) **E8M7** (origin: Ethiopia)
>  2. [Erhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhu) **C5E4** (origin: China)
>  3. **[Balalaika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balalaika)** R6B9 (origin: Russia)
>  4. **[Choghur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choghur)** or **[Chagane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chagane)** A10C7 (origin: Azerbaijan)

Comment: The subheadings ONE, TWO, THREE and FOUR were supposed to give clues about the number of strings in those instruments. You didn't require those clues at all :) Maybe I should have added another layer of abstraction to make those clues useful. @Stiv

Comment: @chandanr777 Ah yes, I didn't actually mention that. For me I already knew of the missing instrument in 3, and it was geography knowledge that helped me pinpoint #4 :)

Comment: Nicely done. I signed up to this puzzling community just yesterday. I am still exploring the responses I get to the different types of questions I post. From what I've seen, you seem to be a veteran here!

Comment: @chandanr777 Well, welcome to the community, and I hope you enjoy your stay!

Comment: Thank you. I most definitely will..